# Javascript date format issue to string

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I convert from  date to String, my date is changing. What is the my fault?

Date is returned me:

```
Date 2016-10-31T22:00:00.000Z
```

And when I convert to String I get:

```
Thu Dec 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

My code:

```
date = new Date("2016 11 31");
StringDate = date.toString();
console.log(StringDate);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after UTC time, which can be printed with [`Date.toUTCString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString):

```
var date = new Date("2016 11 31");
var stringDate = date.toUTCString(); // See this line
console.log(stringDate);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your input is wrong.There is no such date `2016-11-31`. Thats why it shows Dec 01 2016.

Try this:

```
date=new Date("2016 10 31"); //november consist 30 days only
StringDate=date.toString();
console.log(StringDate);
console.log(date);
```